# Read timeout limit for file_get_contents with text file

Tags: php, timeout, file-get-contents

I am using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), with the file being a local text file. I want to add a timeout condition to it.

As of now I only have this:

```
$fileData= file_get_contents($localFile);
```

As per [define a timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$timeout = array('http' => array('timeout' => 1));

$context = stream_context_create($timeout);

$file = file_get_contents('some url',false,$context);
```

How do I implement the timeout(context) array if the source is actually a local file?

**Edit:**
Why do I need this? Well, after I reread my question I realized I missed the purpose, am trying to get the contents of a file, as long as that file is readable within timeout seconds of now.

Comment: how is getting a local file going to timeout on you?

Comment: I'm confused... why do you want this exactly? :s

Answer (score 0):

What if you did something like this

```
$startTime = microtime(true);
while($file === false && ((microtime(true) - $startTime) < 1)){
    $file = file_get_contents('some url');
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is exactly doing? Sorry am a beginner.

Comment: You are getting the time in seconds, then setting your while loop to say as long as you have not read the file or have not passed your execution time continue reading the file.  Note: I have not tried this to even see if it will work.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work. `$startTime = microtime(true);
while($data === false && ((microtime(true) - $startTime) < $timeout)){
    $data = file_get_contents($localFile); 
}
return($data);`

Comment: By didn't work what didn't work, did it not return your data, did it toss an error? I also have to note I think you are going to run out of allocated memory before you hit a time limit unless you are talking hundredths of a second

Comment: By not working I mean it didn't return any data. Am assuming this implies that the read exceeded the maximum execution time.